# Can @Autowire @Service beans but not members of a class instantiated with "new" keyword - even with context scanning configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an app that's been working well with `@Autowired` `@Service` beans.

Now I'm adding a `Validator` class which is instantiated in the Controller:

```
BlueValidator validator = new BlueValidator(colors);
validator.validate(colorBlend, bindResult);
```

In the `BlueValidator` class I'm trying to @Autowire the `blendService` which is working as an `@Autowired` field elsewhere in the app:

```
public class BlueValidator implements Validator {
@Autowired
private BlendService blendService;
private Colors colors;
```

But for some reason after instantiating the BlueValidator, I keep getting `NullPointerException`s for the `blendService`.

Of course I've added the necessary context scanning:

```
<context:component-scan 
base-package="com.myapp.controllers, com.myapp.services, com.myapp.validators" />
```

I also tried adding the`@Autowired` annotation to the constructor but that didn't help:

```
@Autowired
public BlueValidator(Colors colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
}
```

Should I just pass the `blendService` to the `BlueValidator` and forget about the Autowiring or is there something obvious missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you just instantiate an object with `new`, Spring is not involved, so the autowiring won't kick in. Component scanning looks at classes and creates objects from them - it doesn't look at objects you create yourself.

This *can* be made to work, using [Spring's AspectJ support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj), but it takes some effort.

Otherwise, you need to let Spring instantiate your objects if you wan autowiring to work.

> Should I just pass the blendService to the BlueValidator and forget about the Autowiring

In your situation, I'd say yes, this is the least effort solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate objects spring cannot do anything for them, so it does not get the dependencies injected ([article](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=423)).

In your case, you have a couple of options:

- pass dependencies to the validator from the controller (where you can inject them)
- make the validator a spring bean and inject it, instead of instantiating it
- use `@Configurable`, which, via AspectJ, enables spring injection even in objects created with `new`

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` is being used by Spring's `ApplicationContext` to populate those fields on creation.  Since the `ApplicationContext` is not the one creating these beans (you are because of the keyword 'new'), they are not being autowired.  You need to pass it in yourself if you are creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create validator manually -- allow to Spring do this work for you:

```
@Controller
class Controller {

    @Autowired
    BlueValidator validator;

    void doSomething() {
        ...
        validator.validate(colorBlend, bindResult);
        ...
    }

}
```

Also pay attention that adding package `com.myapp.validators` to `context:scan-packages` not enough, you also should annotate your validator class with `@Component` annotation:

```
@Component
public class BlueValidator implements Validator {
@Autowired
private BlendService blendService;
```

(BTW this solution works in my project.)